# Data Type Changing and breaking on very odd line

Tags: c++, thread-safety, eigen

So I have this matrix from the Eigen library.

```
Eigen::MatrixXd
```

And it is filled with data and is 4x3900 points. It is used in a function that has the following lines:

Now the matrix is not even used in this set of code, and for reference it is called modelPointCloud.
Using GDB I step through the lines in the image. For the `workIndex` and `tid` line the matrix is the correct size (ie. 4x3900). But when I step to the next line (`idTableLock`) it is still fine but when i execute that line suddenly the matrix changes to being 0x167 which happens every time but is seemingly a random number.

Now because of that I get this error:

[image]

On this line:

Which makes sense because the matrices are no longer the correct size.

Now other threads are running but none should have access to this data type. Does anyone have an idea about why this is happening? Why would it be that particular line that changes the matrix?

Comment: Please paste the code instead of screenshots

Comment: How did the matrix get to your function?

Comment: Yeah seriously this is extremely difficult to read.

Comment: I usually paste code but this is from QNX which is extremely difficult to communicate with, i have to set up a direct connection and scp the files so i did this instead. @DietmarKühl I dont really understand what you are asking. and Matt Phillips sorry but i dont think it is.

Comment: @Ben: I mean, how is the matrix passed to the function? ... and where does the original matrix live? From the looks of it, the original matrix is created in on thread and passed to another thread. If that's the case, where is the matrix allocated? One potential source of the problem could be that the matrix is allocated on the stack and passed to another thread by pointer. In this case, it would be long gone before the thread accesses it (probably - it may disappear while processing as well).

Comment: @DietmarKühl So the threads are all created within a class and the matrix is a class variable. Currently the error occurs regardless of the number of threads. The matrix is only read by the threads, never written. The master thread creates worker threads which use the matrix in a read fashion, the master will wait for the worker threads to complete. I will look into this but I don't think that the threads are finishing before the matrix is read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that this has nothing to do with Eigen. To me this sounds like memory corruption. You may not directly access the memory through your modelPointCloud variable but are likely writing over the memory that holds the size of the matrix. These types of bugs are quite hard to debug. It's likely you are using an out of bounds index somewhere. Have a look at other [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10968202/debugging-memory-corruption) on this subject.